# C# 12 hour time difference with integers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 14 textboxes that takes a user’s input of two times in a 24 hour clock format. When the calculate button is clicked the difference between the two times is calculated and returns the time in decimal format to the respective label. Ideally I would like the user to simply enter time as an integer, such as 1253 or 925 and select AM or PM from the drop down box. Say a user enters 1115 as the in time with AM selected then enters 300 as the out time with PM selected (as shown in the example entry below), the calculate button is clicked and 3.75 is returned in the label.

[image: gui]

I have this code below and it works but I get errors when there aren’t exactly four characters. First question, how do I fix this so if an integer such as 800 will be read as 8:00 and not error out?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MondayW1InTextBox.Text, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm");
MondayW1Label.Text = timestring;
```

Second, once the string is formatted to 12 hour format, how can I get it to take the AM/PM drop down list as an argument for calculating the difference?

Below is the current C# code behind for just the Monday textboxes calculation which is just 24 hour time format, but want to move away from 24 hour time.

```
protected void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan TimeIn, TimeOut;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(MondayW1InTextBox.Text, out TimeIn)) TimeIn = default(TimeSpan);
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(MondayW1OutTextBox.Text, out TimeOut)) TimeOut = default(TimeSpan);
        MondayW1Label.Text = (TimeOut - TimeIn).TotalHours.ToString("f2");

    }
```

Comment: Not your problem but... you're not accounting for DST transitions. You need an actual date in your calculations.

Comment: I live in Arizona, we don't follow daylight savings.

Comment: Funny. Reminds me of that old C anecdote about a program that only crashes on Wednesdays:  `char dayNames[][9] = {"Wednesday"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is related to the pattern you are using to parse the time: `ParseExact` will always try to match the exact pattern (in your case, `"HHmm"`) to the string being parsed. That means it expects two digits representing the hours and two digits for the minutes. You can easily make it work if you append a leading zero to your string whenever its size is < 4. You can use the `PadLeft` method for doing that:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MondayW1InTextBox.Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The first argument of `PadLeft` is the total length of the resulting string (in our case, 4), and the second argument is the character that should be used to fill in ('0').

For your second problem, you can parse the strings to get the DateTime object and, if the PM value is selected, just add 12 hours to the corresponding time.

```
    DateTime timeIn = DateTime.ParseExact(MondayW1InTextBox.Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime timeOut = DateTime.ParseExact(MondayW1OutTextBox.Text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if(dropDownListIn.SelectedValue == "PM") timeIn = timeIn.AddHours(12);
    if(dropDownListOut.SelectedValue == "PM") timeOut = timeOut.AddHours(12);

    MondayW1Label.Text = (timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
```

Notice that you can use the subtraction operator on `DateTime` objects to get the time difference between them, no need to explicitly convert them to `TimeSpans`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example (it is pretty crude but you get the logic) will be helpful:

```
string datetime1 = "800";
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact((datetime1.Length == 3) ? "0" + datetime1 : datetime1, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string dropDownVal = "AM";
if (dropDownVal == "PM")
    dt1 = dt1.AddHours (12);

string datetime2 = "1100";
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact((datetime2.Length == 3) ? "0" + datetime2 : datetime2, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dropDownVal = "PM";
if (dropDownVal == "PM")
    dt2 = dt2.AddHours (12);

TimeSpan TimeIn, TimeOut;
TimeIn = new TimeSpan (dt1.Ticks);
TimeOut = new TimeSpan(dt2.Ticks);

Console.WriteLine((TimeOut - TimeIn).TotalHours.ToString("f2"));
Console.ReadLine ( );
```